# Terraform: How to assign the value to an attribute based on conditions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How to implement the following login using Terraform?

```
variable "enable_multizone" {
  default = false
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "foo" {
  count = 4
  ...
  if enable_multizone == true:
    zone = data.google_compute_zones.zones.names[count.index % length(data.google_compute_zones.zones.names)]
  else:
    zone = data.google_compute_zones.zones.names[0]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a result like what you described using [conditional expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
  zone = data.google_compute_zones.zones.names[
    var.enable_multizone ?
    count.index % length(data.google_compute_zones.zones.names) :
    0
  ]
```